# Rails create/build with multiple foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i have 3 models on my Rails application:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :expenses
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :expenses

end
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :account
end
```

I want to be able to create an expense only using the account, as in this example:

```
account = current_user.accounts.first
account.expenses.create()
# now a new expense is created with the following data:
# account_id: account.id, user_id: account.user_id
```

Is this possible?
I couldn't find anything similar or anything useful to solve this.

I just want to skip passing user_id when i create the expense and I'm wondering if it s possible.

Thank you.

Comment: a solution would be to create a method for before_validation callback:
  before_validation :set_user_id_from_account
Is this good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the creation scope won't inherit through multiple levels, you can achieve this using a simple `before_validation` hook that assigns<sup>1</sup> from user:

```
class Expense
  before_validation :assign_user_from_account

protected
  def assign_user_from_account
    self.user ||= self.account&.user
  end
end
```

Where here that's possible because `user` can be implied from the Account record.

---

<sup>1</sup> Here I'm using "assign" instead of "set" as "set" is often misconstrued as a mutator method for those from languages that use the `get_x`/`set_x` pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Will this be inefficient, or trigger additional queries?
And more important, is it good practice?

Comment: It will add an additional query to resolve the user. You can trim this down a little by using `self.user_id ||= self.account.user_id` if that's a concern, but I find that in practice this sort of overhead is pretty marginal unless you're dealing with an extremely active operation on a very active (e.g. 1K req/s.) deployment.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of inserts, don't forget you can do things like [`insert_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all) which is generally way more efficient than bashing out individual record `save` calls.

Comment: Thank you for this, it works as expected.